# Possible to run a React + Web API project from Visual Studio IDE? Getting Launching the SPA proxy

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a single Asp.Net Core Web API + React project.
Basically this project contains the API and the UI.

When I debug run this project from Visual Studio 2022, it does the following:

1. Starts a browser on https://localhost:3000 which says
   "Launching the SPA proxy..."
   "This page will automatically redirect to https://localhost:7070 when the SPA proxy is ready."
2. Then a console starts with title "npm". And it says:
   "Something is already running on port 3000"
   "Would you like to run the app on another port instead? » (Y/n)"
3. It keeps opening a new console (repeating step 2).

What must I do to break this seemingly infinite loop and get this project to run locally?